# WYSIWYG HTML Editor WPF

Tags: wpf, wysiwyg

I need to implement a full fledged WYSIWYG HTML Editor in WPF, with a property grid for editing an elements css.

I have seen countless examples using richtext /web views etc.
The problem with all of them are that there's no way for the html element to communicate with the view.

Is there a control that supports this?

Answer (score 1):

[Smith HTML Editor](http://smithhtmleditor.codeplex.com/) is the only one I know of that is used by my colleagues. But my current experience with it is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may try SpiceLogic WPF HTML Editor Control. This editor is good when you are looking for optimized XHTML directly from the editor.

https://www.spicelogic.com/Products/WPF-HTML-Editor-Control-17

[image]